# How to set the size of the arc in ChartJS?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I can’t set the arc size for the chart. How to set the size of the arc? Also, I can’t make the animation work, although I took an example from the official documentation :/

[image]

Here is my code:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart-<%= ChartId %>').getContext('2d');

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
 type: 'doughnut',
 data: {
     datasets: [{
         data: [
             11,69,20
         ],
         backgroundColor: [
             "#ffb74d",
             "#4db6ac",
             "#bf360c"
         ]
     }]
 },
 options: {
     tooltips: {
          enabled: false
     },
     plugins: {
         labels: {
             render: 'percentage',
             precision: 2,
             showZero: true,
             fontSize: 30,
             fontColor: ['#2c405a', '#2c405a', 'white'],
             fontFamily: "PTSansBold",
         }
     },
     animation: {
         duration:5000
     }
 }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Config Options](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/doughnut.html#config-options), `cutoutPercentage` defines the percentage of the chart that is cut out of the middle. To also make animation work, place the `canvas` inside a `div` and add `responsive: true` to your `options`.

```
options: {
   responsive: true,
   cutoutPercentage: 30,
   ...
}
```

The animations works fine with what you defined in your options.

```js
var myChart = new Chart(document.getElementById('myChart'), {
   type: 'doughnut',   
   data: {
     datasets: [{
         data: [
             11,69,20
         ],
         backgroundColor: [
             "#ffb74d",
             "#4db6ac",
             "#bf360c"
         ]
     }]
   },
   options: {
     responsive:true,
     cutoutPercentage: 60,
     tooltips: {
          enabled: false
     },
     plugins: {
         labels: {
             render: 'percentage',
             precision: 2,
             showZero: true,
             fontSize: 30,
             fontColor: ['#2c405a', '#2c405a', 'white'],
             fontFamily: "PTSansBold",
         }
     },
     animation: {
         duration: 5000
     }
   }
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! It helps me! My animation error was caused by setting a fixed size for canvas

Answer (score 2):

if anyone looking for fix as per chartJS 3 and year-2022

they have changes some configurations and this will work as follow

```
options: {
   cutout: 80,
   ...
}
```

Comment: If specifying percentage then the value must be a string with the percent sign too. E.g. `cutout: "80%"`. Otherwise it will be interpreted as pixels. See https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/doughnut.html#config-options

Answer (score 1):

The doughnut/pie chart allows a number of properties to be specified for each dataset. These are used to set display properties for a specific dataset.

For example, if you want to change the width of the border there is an option of `cutoutPercentage`.

```
options: {
   cutoutPercentage: 80,
   ...
}
```

Similarly, you can find other options from the official documentation.

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/doughnut.html

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('chart').getContext('2d');

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
 type: 'doughnut',
 data: {
     datasets: [{
         data: [
             11,69,20
         ],
         backgroundColor: [
             "#ffb74d",
             "#4db6ac",
             "#bf360c"
         ]
     }]
 },
 options: {
     cutoutPercentage: 80,
     animation: {
         duration:5000
     }
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart"></canvas>
```

I hope this helps. Please let me know if you have any doubt.